# eslint erofs read only- doest not match with any directory

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

anyone know what i have to do? the problem apper when i use linux dual boot, when i use window have no problem.

```js
ERROR in [eslint] EROFS: read-only file system, open '/media/naufal/6878124278121004/Refactory/Skill-Test-Refactory/miniApp/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache'

webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, it looks like your node has not been updated. you can try to update first.

Comment: oke dude, i wil try it to update my package